# Hibernate: Dealing with unique contraints

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a table called Topic with two columns: Id(Primary key) and topic(Unique key).

I need to avoid duplicate entries to column 'topic'.

Here is the domain class for the table.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TOPIC",uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "TOPIC") })
@DynamicUpdate
ublic class Topic { 
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="ID")
private long id;

@Column(name="TOPIC",unique=true)
private String topic;
//getters and setters
```

When I'am inserting duplicate entry,it is trowing sql exception (org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Duplicate entry ).So iam catching that exception and showing a message "item already exists)

```
    try {

        topicService.save(tp);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.print("item already exists");

    }
```

is this the correct method for dealing with unique constraints in Spring data JPA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it is a one column then this should be enough:

```
@Column(name="TOPIC",unique=true)
private String topic;
```

if unique applies to more than  one column combined together , let's say : `TOPIC` and `REF` :@Entity

```
@Table(name="TOPIC",uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"TOPIC","REF"}) )
@DynamicUpdate
public class Topic { 
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="ID")
private long id;

@Column(name="TOPIC")
private String topic;
@Column(name="REF")
private String ref;
//getters and setters
```

if you have multiple combined unique constraints for example :{`TOPIC` ,`REF` } AND {`VERSION`,"TOPIC"}

```
    @Table(name="TOPIC",uniqueConstraints ={ @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"TOPIC","REF"}),@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"TOPIC","VERSION"})})
public class Topic { 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="ID")
    private long id;

    @Column(name="TOPIC")
    private String topic;
    @Column(name="REF")
    private String ref;
    //getters and setters
    @Column(name="VERSION")
    private String version;
```

Comment: ok. But when I'am adding the duplicate data its trowing sql exception.Wont hibernate handle this by itself without trowing exception?

Comment: no you have to handle that byyourself, at the DAO level for exampl: try { save your entity }catch(`DataIntegrityViolationException` e){ //handle it here }